# Why do I have two 'Macintosh HD - Data' partitions?

Tags: macos, partition

I recently reinstalled macOS from a USB pendrive to be able to upgrade my 128 GB SSD to Big Sur. For some reason I now have two 'Macintosh HD - Data' partitions:

[image]
[image]
[image]

What's the second 'Macintosh HD - Data' partition doing here? And can I safely remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume disk1s1 mounted as /Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data as no utility.
You can suppress by the terminal command:

`diskutil ap deletevolume disk1s1`